# Common 四{よ}字{じ}熟{じゅく}語{ご} that use/are 当{あ}て字{じ}

Tags: words, kanji, compounds, ateji

Are there any commonly <strike>used</strike> known 四{よ}字{じ}熟{じゅく}語{ご}　that use/are 当{あ}て字{じ} besides the following?  Just crossed my mind, and now I'm curious.

滅{め}茶{ちゃ}苦{く}茶{ちゃ}, 夜{よ}露{ろ}死{し}苦{く}, 無{む}理{り}矢{や}理{り}

Comment: I would not say that 夜露死苦 is commonly used….

Comment: OK, "commonly known"

Comment: Thanks for the edit.  By the way, I do not know the definition of 四字熟語, and I am not sure if these ateji words qualify as 四字熟語 at all.  If we take 四字熟語 simply as a word written as four kanji characters (which is the literal and the broadest meaning of 四字熟語), then there are many foreign names which _can_ be written as kanji, some of which consist of four kanji: see e.g. http://homepage3.nifty.com/maryy/japanese/country-names.htm.  But most of them are not commonly used or even commonly known.

Comment: Are questions of this type allowed?  From the FAQ: "You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: I wouldn't say 無理矢理 is completely ateji. Only the 矢理 part is ateji.

Comment: I thought "Ateji" was 宛て字?  Seems like both come up in my IME..

Comment: @Boaz - yes, only the 矢理 part is ateji.

@makdad - yes, 宛字 is another valid spelling (although without the て since 宛 is "ate" by itself according to my dictionaries)

@Amanda - well, practicality seems like a very subjective measure (what's practical to me may not be practical to you), it's definitely answerable (whether or not by anyone on this site is another thing) and I actively study 四字熟語 so it seems like a valid "problem".  My $0.02

Comment: @ist, So, do you just want the list of those? I think I would go through around 2000 words and will pick up possible list, but I doubt I can't explain those one by one.

Comment: @istrasci The practicality part was not my main issue with this question (though this does seem more like trivia than practical knowledge, and to get good answers it might help to explain what you are going to do with them).  My main issue was that it might be unanswerable.  If there are hundreds of such compounds, it would be very difficult to find them all and fit them in one definitive answer.  This makes it hard to mark any answer to this question right or wrong, which defeats the purpose of the SE model.

Comment: I see 3 close votes on this question.  It's true: it's a 'list of x' question.  However, if a 'list of x' question has enough value, it can be converted to community wiki instead of closed and deleted.  (It's actually in the description for "convert to wiki".)  What do you say, community?  Shall we CW it instead of closing it?

Answer (score 6):

Here is the list, I've filterd from dictionary with a script, and added links to jisho.org for reference.

Regarding commonness, I would choose some like 伊勢海老, 回転寿司, 有耶無耶, 大馬鹿者, 我武者羅, 興味津津, 一人相撲, 滅茶苦茶, 読売新聞.

> 「[浅草海苔](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%B5%85%E8%8D%89%E6%B5%B7%E8%8B%94&eng=&dict=edict)」 あさくさのり
>
> 「[彼方此方](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%BD%BC%E6%96%B9%E6%AD%A4%E6%96%B9&eng=&dict=edict)」 あちこち
>
> 「[阿仏利加](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E9%98%BF%E4%BB%8F%E5%88%A9%E5%8A%A0&eng=&dict=edict)」 あふりか
>
> 「[亜刺比亜](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E4%BA%9C%E5%88%BA%E6%AF%94%E4%BA%9C&eng=&dict=edict)」 あらびあ
>
> 「[亜爾加里](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E4%BA%9C%E7%88%BE%E5%8A%A0%E9%87%8C&eng=&dict=edict)」 あるかり
>
> 「[安母尼亜](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%AE%89%E6%AF%8D%E5%B0%BC%E4%BA%9C&eng=&dict=edict)」 あんもにあ
>
> 「[如何様師](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%A6%82%E4%BD%95%E6%A7%98%E5%B8%AB&eng=&dict=edict)」 いかさまし
>
> 「[伊勢海老](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E4%BC%8A%E5%8B%A2%E6%B5%B7%E8%80%81&eng=&dict=edict)」 いせえび
>
> 「[稲荷寿司](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%A8%B2%E8%8D%B7%E5%AF%BF%E5%8F%B8&eng=&dict=edict)」 いなりずし
>
> 「[薄羽蜉蝣](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%96%84%E7%BE%BD%E8%9C%89%E8%9D%A3&eng=&dict=edict)」 うすばかげろう
>
> 「[有耶無耶](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%9C%89%E8%80%B6%E7%84%A1%E8%80%B6&eng=&dict=edict)」 うやむや
>
> 「[迂路迂路](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%BF%82%E8%B7%AF%E8%BF%82%E8%B7%AF&eng=&dict=edict)」 うろうろ
>
> 「[葡萄茶色](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%91%A1%E8%90%84%E8%8C%B6%E8%89%B2&eng=&dict=edict)」 えびちゃいろ
>
> 「[閻魔羅闍](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E9%96%BB%E9%AD%94%E7%BE%85%E9%97%8D&eng=&dict=edict)」 えんま、えんまらじゃ
>
> 「[大馬鹿者](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%A4%A7%E9%A6%AC%E9%B9%BF%E8%80%85&eng=&dict=edict)」 おおばかもの
>
> 「[大盤振舞](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%A4%A7%E7%9B%A4%E6%8C%AF%E8%88%9E&eng=&dict=edict)」 おおばんぶるまい
>
> 「[御粗末様](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%BE%A1%E7%B2%97%E6%9C%AB%E6%A7%98&eng=&dict=edict)」 おそまつさま
>
> 「[未通女娘](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%9C%AA%E9%80%9A%E5%A5%B3%E5%A8%98&eng=&dict=edict)」 おぼこむすめ
>
> 「[御御御付](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%BE%A1%E5%BE%A1%E5%BE%A1%E4%BB%98&eng=&dict=edict)」 おみおつけ
>
> 「[阿容阿容](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E9%98%BF%E5%AE%B9%E9%98%BF%E5%AE%B9&eng=&dict=edict)」 おめおめ
>
> 「[御目出度](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%BE%A1%E7%9B%AE%E5%87%BA%E5%BA%A6&eng=&dict=edict)」 おめでた
>
> 「[御芽出度](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%BE%A1%E8%8A%BD%E5%87%BA%E5%BA%A6&eng=&dict=edict)」 おめでた
>
> 「[御目文字](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%BE%A1%E7%9B%AE%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97&eng=&dict=edict)」 おめもじ
>
> 「[濠斯剌利](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%BF%A0%E6%96%AF%E5%89%8C%E5%88%A9&eng=&dict=edict)」 おーすとらりあ
>
> 「[懐中時計](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%87%90%E4%B8%AD%E6%99%82%E8%A8%88&eng=&dict=edict)」 かいちゅうどけい
>
> 「[回転寿司](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%9B%9E%E8%BB%A2%E5%AF%BF%E5%8F%B8&eng=&dict=edict)」 かいてんずし
>
> 「[柿葉寿司](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%9F%BF%E8%91%89%E5%AF%BF%E5%8F%B8&eng=&dict=edict)」 かきのはずし
>
> 「[加須底羅](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%8A%A0%E9%A0%88%E5%BA%95%E7%BE%85&eng=&dict=edict)」 かすてら
>
> 「[漢風諡号](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%BC%A2%E9%A2%A8%E8%AB%A1%E5%8F%B7&eng=&dict=edict)」 かんふうしごう
>
> 「[我武者羅](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%88%91%E6%AD%A6%E8%80%85%E7%BE%85&eng=&dict=edict)」 がむしゃら
>
> 「[我利我利](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%88%91%E5%88%A9%E6%88%91%E5%88%A9&eng=&dict=edict)」 がりがり
>
> 「[生真面目](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%94%9F%E7%9C%9F%E9%9D%A2%E7%9B%AE&eng=&dict=edict)」 きまじめ
>
> 「[興味津々](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%88%88%E5%91%B3%E6%B4%A5%E3%80%85&eng=&dict=edict)」 きょうみしんしん
>
> 「[興味津津](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%88%88%E5%91%B3%E6%B4%A5%E6%B4%A5&eng=&dict=edict)」 きょうみしんしん
>
> 「[吉利支丹](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%90%89%E5%88%A9%E6%94%AF%E4%B8%B9&eng=&dict=edict)」 きりしたん
>
> 「[基督教徒](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%9F%BA%E7%9D%A3%E6%95%99%E5%BE%92&eng=&dict=edict)」 きりすときょうと
>
> 「[金平牛蒡](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E9%87%91%E5%B9%B3%E7%89%9B%E8%92%A1&eng=&dict=edict)」 きんぴらごぼう
>
> 「[祇園囃子](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%A5%87%E5%9C%92%E5%9B%83%E5%AD%90&eng=&dict=edict)」 ぎおんばやし
>
> 「[盟神探湯](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%9B%9F%E7%A5%9E%E6%8E%A2%E6%B9%AF&eng=&dict=edict)」 くかたち
>
> 「[屎真面目](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%B1%8E%E7%9C%9F%E9%9D%A2%E7%9B%AE&eng=&dict=edict)」 くそまじめ
>
> 「[糞真面目](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%B3%9E%E7%9C%9F%E9%9D%A2%E7%9B%AE&eng=&dict=edict)」 くそまじめ
>
> 「[紅旗征戎](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%B4%85%E6%97%97%E5%BE%81%E6%88%8E&eng=&dict=edict)」 こうきせいじゅう
>
> 「[古加乙涅](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%8F%A4%E5%8A%A0%E4%B9%99%E6%B6%85&eng=&dict=edict)」 こかいん
>
> 「[国風諡号](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%9B%BD%E9%A2%A8%E8%AB%A1%E5%8F%B7&eng=&dict=edict)」 こくふうしごう
>
> 「[小春日和](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%B0%8F%E6%98%A5%E6%97%A5%E5%92%8C&eng=&dict=edict)」 こはるびより
>
> 「[哥白尼的](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%93%A5%E7%99%BD%E5%B0%BC%E7%9A%84&eng=&dict=edict)」 こぺるにくすてき
>
> 「[哥倫比亜](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%93%A5%E5%80%AB%E6%AF%94%E4%BA%9C&eng=&dict=edict)」 ころんびあ
>
> 「[御無沙汰](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%BE%A1%E7%84%A1%E6%B2%99%E6%B1%B0&eng=&dict=edict)」 ごぶさた
>
> 「[四柱推命](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%9B%9B%E6%9F%B1%E6%8E%A8%E5%91%BD&eng=&dict=edict)」 しちゅうすいめい
>
> 「[西比利亜](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%A5%BF%E6%AF%94%E5%88%A9%E4%BA%9C&eng=&dict=edict)」 しべりあ
>
> 「[七五三縄](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E4%B8%83%E4%BA%94%E4%B8%89%E7%B8%84&eng=&dict=edict)」 しめなわ
>
> 「[焦眉之急](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%84%A6%E7%9C%89%E4%B9%8B%E6%80%A5&eng=&dict=edict)」 しょうびのきゅう
>
> 「[不知不識](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E4%B8%8D%E7%9F%A5%E4%B8%8D%E8%AD%98&eng=&dict=edict)」 しらずしらず
>
> 「[地下足袋](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%9C%B0%E4%B8%8B%E8%B6%B3%E8%A2%8B&eng=&dict=edict)」 じかたび
>
> 「[常套手段](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%B8%B8%E5%A5%97%E6%89%8B%E6%AE%B5&eng=&dict=edict)」 じょうとうしゅだん
>
> 「[成吉思汗](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%88%90%E5%90%89%E6%80%9D%E6%B1%97&eng=&dict=edict)」 じんぎすかん
>
> 「[寸断寸断](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%AF%B8%E6%96%AD%E5%AF%B8%E6%96%AD&eng=&dict=edict)」 ずたずた
>
> 「[大正海老](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%A4%A7%E6%AD%A3%E6%B5%B7%E8%80%81&eng=&dict=edict)」 たいしょうえび
>
> 「[達頼喇嘛](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E9%81%94%E9%A0%BC%E5%96%87%E5%98%9B&eng=&dict=edict)」 だらいらま
>
> 「[腸窒扶斯](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%85%B8%E7%AA%92%E6%89%B6%E6%96%AF&eng=&dict=edict)」 ちょうちふす
>
> 「[九十九折](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E4%B9%9D%E5%8D%81%E4%B9%9D%E6%8A%98&eng=&dict=edict)」 つづらおり
>
> 「[梃子入策](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%A2%83%E5%AD%90%E5%85%A5%E7%AD%96&eng=&dict=edict)」 てこいれさく
>
> 「[天爾遠波](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%A4%A9%E7%88%BE%E9%81%A0%E6%B3%A2&eng=&dict=edict)」 てにをは
>
> 「[弖爾乎波](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%BC%96%E7%88%BE%E4%B9%8E%E6%B3%A2&eng=&dict=edict)」 てにをは
>
> 「[手巻寿司](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%89%8B%E5%B7%BB%E5%AF%BF%E5%8F%B8&eng=&dict=edict)」 てまきずし
>
> 「[手鞠寿司](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%89%8B%E9%9E%A0%E5%AF%BF%E5%8F%B8&eng=&dict=edict)」 てまりずし
>
> 「[天手古舞](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%A4%A9%E6%89%8B%E5%8F%A4%E8%88%9E&eng=&dict=edict)」 てんてこまい
>
> 「[転手古舞](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%BB%A2%E6%89%8B%E5%8F%A4%E8%88%9E&eng=&dict=edict)」 てんてこまい
>
> 「[天婦羅油](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%A4%A9%E5%A9%A6%E7%BE%85%E6%B2%B9&eng=&dict=edict)」 てんぷらあぶら、てんぷらゆ
>
> 「[天麩羅油](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%A4%A9%E9%BA%A9%E7%BE%85%E6%B2%B9&eng=&dict=edict)」 てんぷらあぶら、てんぷらゆ
>
> 「[浪花節的](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%B5%AA%E8%8A%B1%E7%AF%80%E7%9A%84&eng=&dict=edict)」 なにわぶしてき
>
> 「[再従兄弟](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%86%8D%E5%BE%93%E5%85%84%E5%BC%9F&eng=&dict=edict)」 はとこ
>
> 「[再従姉妹](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%86%8D%E5%BE%93%E5%A7%89%E5%A6%B9&eng=&dict=edict)」 はとこ
>
> 「[馬鹿正直](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E9%A6%AC%E9%B9%BF%E6%AD%A3%E7%9B%B4&eng=&dict=edict)」 ばかしょうじき
>
> 「[馬鹿野郎](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E9%A6%AC%E9%B9%BF%E9%87%8E%E9%83%8E&eng=&dict=edict)」 ばかやろう
>
> 「[比斯的里](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%AF%94%E6%96%AF%E7%9A%84%E9%87%8C&eng=&dict=edict)」 ひすてりー
>
> 「[一人相撲](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E4%B8%80%E4%BA%BA%E7%9B%B8%E6%92%B2&eng=&dict=edict)」 ひとりずもう
>
> 「[不真面目](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E4%B8%8D%E7%9C%9F%E9%9D%A2%E7%9B%AE&eng=&dict=edict)」 ふまじめ
>
> 「[襤褸襤褸](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%A5%A4%E8%A4%B8%E8%A5%A4%E8%A4%B8&eng=&dict=edict)」 ぼろぼろ
>
> 「[麻剌利亜](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E9%BA%BB%E5%89%8C%E5%88%A9%E4%BA%9C&eng=&dict=edict)」 まらりあ
>
> 「[曼殊沙華](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%9B%BC%E6%AE%8A%E6%B2%99%E8%8F%AF&eng=&dict=edict)」 まんじゅしゃげ
>
> 「[曼珠沙華](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%9B%BC%E7%8F%A0%E6%B2%99%E8%8F%AF&eng=&dict=edict)」 まんじゅしゃげ
>
> 「[万葉仮名](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E4%B8%87%E8%91%89%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D&eng=&dict=edict)」 まんようがな
>
> 「[萬葉仮名](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%90%AC%E8%91%89%E4%BB%AE%E5%90%8D&eng=&dict=edict)」 まんようがな
>
> 「[米西西皮](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%B1%B3%E8%A5%BF%E8%A5%BF%E7%9A%AE&eng=&dict=edict)」 みししっぴー
>
> 「[土産品店](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%9C%9F%E7%94%A3%E5%93%81%E5%BA%97&eng=&dict=edict)」 みやげひんてん
>
> 「[武者振付](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%AD%A6%E8%80%85%E6%8C%AF%E4%BB%98&eng=&dict=edict)」 むしゃぶりつ
>
> 「[無茶苦茶](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%84%A1%E8%8C%B6%E8%8B%A6%E8%8C%B6&eng=&dict=edict)」 むちゃくちゃ
>
> 「[無暗矢鱈](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%84%A1%E6%9A%97%E7%9F%A2%E9%B1%88&eng=&dict=edict)」 むやみやたら
>
> 「[無闇矢鱈](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%84%A1%E9%97%87%E7%9F%A2%E9%B1%88&eng=&dict=edict)」 むやみやたら
>
> 「[滅茶苦茶](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%BB%85%E8%8C%B6%E8%8B%A6%E8%8C%B6&eng=&dict=edict)」 めちゃくちゃ
>
> 「[目茶苦茶](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%9B%AE%E8%8C%B6%E8%8B%A6%E8%8C%B6&eng=&dict=edict)」 めちゃくちゃ
>
> 「[滅茶滅茶](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%BB%85%E8%8C%B6%E6%BB%85%E8%8C%B6&eng=&dict=edict)」 めちゃめちゃ
>
> 「[目茶目茶](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%9B%AE%E8%8C%B6%E7%9B%AE%E8%8C%B6&eng=&dict=edict)」 めちゃめちゃ
>
> 「[滅多矢鱈](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%BB%85%E5%A4%9A%E7%9F%A2%E9%B1%88&eng=&dict=edict)」 めったやたら
>
> 「[元木阿彌](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%85%83%E6%9C%A8%E9%98%BF%E5%BD%8C&eng=&dict=edict)」 もとのもくあみ
>
> 「[莫爾比涅](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%8E%AB%E7%88%BE%E6%AF%94%E6%B6%85&eng=&dict=edict)」 もるひね
>
> 「[門土里留](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E9%96%80%E5%9C%9F%E9%87%8C%E7%95%99&eng=&dict=edict)」 もんとりおーる
>
> 「[翻筋斗打](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%BF%BB%E7%AD%8B%E6%96%97%E6%89%93&eng=&dict=edict)」 もんどりう
>
> 「[大和言葉](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%A4%A7%E5%92%8C%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89&eng=&dict=edict)」 やまとことば
>
> 「[夢見心地](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%A4%A2%E8%A6%8B%E5%BF%83%E5%9C%B0&eng=&dict=edict)」 ゆめみごこち
>
> 「[読売新聞](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%AA%AD%E5%A3%B2%E6%96%B0%E8%81%9E&eng=&dict=edict)」 よみうりしんぶん
>
> 「[讀賣新聞](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E8%AE%80%E8%B3%A3%E6%96%B0%E8%81%9E&eng=&dict=edict)」 よみうりしんぶん
>
> 「[四方山話](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%9B%9B%E6%96%B9%E5%B1%B1%E8%A9%B1&eng=&dict=edict)」 よもやまばなし
>
> 「[羅馬尼亜](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E7%BE%85%E9%A6%AC%E5%B0%BC%E4%BA%9C&eng=&dict=edict)」 るーまにあ
>
> 「[六波羅蜜](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%85%AD%E6%B3%A2%E7%BE%85%E8%9C%9C&eng=&dict=edict)」 ろくはらみつ
>
> 「[没分暁漢](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%B2%A1%E5%88%86%E6%9A%81%E6%BC%A2&eng=&dict=edict)」 わからずや
>
> 「[倭菓子店](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%80%AD%E8%8F%93%E5%AD%90%E5%BA%97&eng=&dict=edict)」 わがしてん
>
> 「[和菓子店](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%92%8C%E8%8F%93%E5%AD%90%E5%BA%97&eng=&dict=edict)」 わがしてん
>
> 「[倭菓子屋](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E5%80%AD%E8%8F%93%E5%AD%90%E5%B1%8B&eng=&dict=edict)」 わがしや
>
> 「[悪巫山戯](http://jisho.org/words?jap=%E6%82%AA%E5%B7%AB%E5%B1%B1%E6%88%AF&eng=&dict=edict)」 わるふざけ